# Error refreshing external data

Tags: business-intelligence, bi

I have an Excel sheet that retrieves data from a SharePoint list. I want to display this Excel sheet in my BI center, however it gives me this error that

> SharePoint lists are not supported

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to use oData feed and sharepoint api to retrieve list information.